# Why doesn't this template code work?

Tags: c++, templates

They told me to use templates to find the sum. Why doesn't this work? Thanks.

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
auto add(A a, B b, C c = a + b) -> decltype(c) {
    return c;
}
```

I thought C++11 said you can use the arguments after they are declared. Why doesn't this work then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use arguments as the value of defaults. Also, template type deduction doesn't work that way.

Just write it like this:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
auto add(A a, B b) -> decltype(a + b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

And hope C++ gets return type deduction soon.

Comment: do i always have to use decltype where i do auto in functions?

Comment: Is the `c` in `decltype(a + c)` a typo?

Comment: @David, only when you cannot predict the resulting type of an expression, as is the case of an expression involving templated arguments. You cannot possibly know whether these arguments are `float`s, `int`s, a mix of both, or something else.